# Validating list elements are unique in marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

I would like to understand if I can use **marshmallow** validate function to check whether all elements in a list are unique.

I have the following schema:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate

class PaymentSchema(Schema):
    ...
    currencies = fields.List(
        fields.String(
            required=True,
            validate=[
                validate.OneOf(["USD", "EUR", "AUS", "GBP"]),
                validate.Length(min=1, max=4)
            ]
        )
    )
```

Is there any possibility to guarantee that given a list of currencies with duplicated currencies (`["USD", "EUR", "EUR"]`) raises a *ValidationError*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`validates` decorator](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#field-validators-as-methods) allows custom validation:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, ValidationError, fields, validate, validates

class PaymentSchema(Schema):
    currencies = fields.List(
        fields.String(
            required=True,
            validate=[
                validate.OneOf(["USD", "EUR", "AUS", "GBP"]),
                validate.Length(min=1, max=4)
            ]
        )
    )

    @validates('currencies')
    def no_duplicate_currencies(self, value):
        if len(value) != len(set(value)):
            raise ValidationError('currencies must not contain duplicate elements')
```